# How to get Facebook Messenger on my iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone

I can't get Facebook Messenger on my iPhone 3GS. When I reset my phone, it made a new account. Now it just says I need iOS 7. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 isnt compatible with iPhone 3Gs.

You need to upgrade your phone.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your phone. you're not going to be able to install current apps on your 3GS as your limited to running iOS 6.